# How to define a correct XSLT?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

Assuming I have the following XML and I care only about the FruitId, and the customer Numbereaten, and Weight attributes.

```
<AllFruits xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<!-- All fruits below. -->
<Fruit>
  <FruitId>Bannana</FruitId>
  <FruitColor>Yellow</FruitColor>
  <FruitShape>Moon</FruitShape>
  <Customer>
     <Name>Joe</Name>
     <Numbereaten>5</NumberEaten>
     <Weight>2.6</Weight>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
     <Name>Mark</Name>
     <Numbereaten>8</NumberEaten>
     <Weight>5.0</Weight>
  </Customer>
</Fruit>
<Fruit>
  <FruitId>Apple</FruitId>
  <FruitColor>Red</FruitColor>
  <FruitShape>Circle</FruitShape>
  <Customer>
     <Name>Joe</Name>
     <Numbereaten>2</NumberEaten>
     <Weight>1.5</Weight>
  </Customer>
</Fruit>
<Fruit>
  <FruitId>Pear</FruitId>
  <FruitColor>Green</FruitColor>
  <FruitShape>Oval</FruitShape>
  <Customer>
     <Name>Mark</Name>
     <NumberEaten>1</NumberEaten>
     <Weight>6</Weight>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
     <Name>Josh</Name>
     <NumberEaten>9</NumberEaten>
     <Weight>10</Weight>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
     <Name>Willis</Name>
     <NumberEaten>2</NumberEaten>
     <Weight>5.6</Weight>
  </Customer>
</Fruit>
</AllFruits>
```

What is the proper XSLT for the above? I tried the following, but it did not work.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="ISO-8859-1" />
    <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#xA;'"/>
    <xsl:template match="Fruit">
        <xsl:for-each select="Customer">
            <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::FruitId" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Numbereaten" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Weight" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To attempt to test the XSLT, I use the following Java code:

```
   Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(new File("xmlFile"));
   Source xsltSource = new StreamSource(new File("xsltFile"));
   Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(xsltSource);
   transformer.transform(xmlSource, new StreamResult(System.out));
```

All that I am getting is the XML being output into the console... not in the format I would desire like:

```
Bannana, 5, 2.6
Bannana, 8, 5
...
Apple 6, 5
Apple 3, 2
```

If what I am trying to do does not work, if there are other better approaches other than XSLT let me know. It feels like something like this should be simple.

Comment: Use this page for testing your XSLT file http://xslttest.appspot.com/ and you will see it works

Comment: @KnutHerrmann Thanks for sharing the test link. It's very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually doing a `copy` transformation i.e. no stylesheet transformations are being applied. This is the reason why you're simply seeing the contents of your source XML file as the output on your console.

To apply the stylesheet you need to set it while getting an instance of your `Transformer`

```
Source stylesource = new StreamSource(new File("/path/to/your/stylesheet.xsl"));
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(stylesource);
```

***XSLT Output:***

```
Bannana,5,2.6
Bannana,8,5.0

Apple,2,1.5

Pear,1,6
Pear,9,10
Pear,2,5.6
```

Comment: I need the XSL only to extract the information I need such that it outputs in a "CSV" like format. Updated question with expected output.

Comment: Getting a fatal error after your recommendation: [Fatal Error] Fruits.xslt: The prefix "xsl" for element "xsl:stylesheet" is not bound.
ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
           :The prefix "xsl" for element "xsl:stylesheet" is not bound.

Comment: Please remove `xmlns:xsl` from your input xml (from <AllFruits>) and your xml isn't well formed. Check your <NumberEaten> tags. They don't use the same case everywhere. Fix that as well.

Comment: Fixed case and removed xmlns:xsl from input file, getting the same error.... Ugh "The prefix "xsl" for element "xsl:stylesheet" is not found".

Comment: Are you sure you've specified `xmlns` as `xmlns:xsl` and not `xmlns:xslt` for `<xsl:stylesheet>`?

Comment: I specified xmlns the exact same way as shown in my original question, there is no xmlns:xslt anywhere. What changes should I make to the original files?

Comment: Let's debug the XSLT. Try to compile a blank xslt file first. That means with just the <xsl:stylesheet> (with namespace) start and end tags and all of its contents removed (<xsl:value-of> etc.). If this works fine keep adding one line at a time till you hit the error. (Note when it comes to adding <xsl:template> add a blank template first i.e. which does nothing.)

Comment: I just ran the code in Eclipse. Everything works fine mate. You need to work on your xslt rules though as I got `Bannana,,2.6` as output. Ah, it's working as expected now. Just had to change Numbereaten to NumberEaten in xslt. Did you get it working?

Comment: Close... does not work with any additional fruits <Fruit></Fruit>. I.e. Apple. The output appears to be: Bannana,5,2.6
Bannana,8,5.0
Apple,5,2.6
Apple,8,5.0. Notice how the values of Apple are the same of that of the Bannana even though the .xml file contains different values for the Apple fruitid'ed fruit. I've replaced the <Fruit>...</Fruit> I had in my original post with "Apple" and "Pear".

Comment: That's because your input xml has `<NumberEaten>` tags for the rest of your fruits. Stick to either `eaten` or `Eaten` in both your input as well as xslt. (Your xslt uses `eaten`. I had changed that as well when I tested on my machine.)

Comment: @Damascusi Updated answer with the XSLT output.

Comment: @Damascusi Please consider an up vote. Spent a lot of time on this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get rid of the empty lines just add in your XSLT file after line

```
<xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#xA;'"/>
```

this line

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `xslStream` being used ?

**Do this:**

```
Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(new File("xmlFile"));
Source xsltSource = new StreamSource(new File("xsltFile"));

TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xsltSource);
transformer.transform(xmlSource, System.out);
```

Comment: Getting a [Fatal Error] Fruits.xslt: The prefix "xsl" for element "xsl:stylesheet" is not bound.
ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
           :The prefix "xsl" for element "xsl:stylesheet" is not bound.

Comment: @Damascusi, what format you want output in ? HTML DOM or anything else in particular ?

Comment: I would like output in a csv format (similar to the one in my question). Comma separated on the "FruitId, NumberEaten, Weight".

Comment: @Damascusi, can you please post your current xml output ?

Comment: After making the change in your post, I am not getting any xml output, just the Fatal Error aforementioned.

Comment: @Damascusi, The output you get is HTML DOM format. You will have to traverse through HTML and write the output.

Comment: Remove `xmlns:xsl` from your xml as @ravi has suggested. That is not well formatted XML.

Comment: Made the corrections to case, removed xmlns:xsl from the .xml file. The same Fatal Error occurs. Appears the problem is with my xslt file...  "The prefix "xsl" for element "xsl:stylesheet" is not found".

Comment: @Damascusi Yes, the problem does seem to be with your xslt but the problems with your input xml would have also bugged you later on.